# OpenLayers2 WMS layers and overlay, even official samples are broken?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using a library that requires OL2 (sadly, i wish i could go OL3 but that's not an option).

What i need is to display different WMS base layers with some other WMS overlays.

Point is, i don't understand what i'm doing wrong. This library is supposed to give me an ol.wms layer, but it doesn't work. I'm trying to understand how this thing works, but even the documentation and samples on the official website are broken.

Some examples:

- http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wrapDateLine.html
- http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/getfeature-wfs.html
- http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/tilecache.html
- http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wms-long-url.html

It seems to me that these examples are outdated (i tried on firefox 40, chrome 45, even IE11...) which is understandable since it's a 2 years old library, but i sadly need them.

Can anybody point me to updated samples, if available?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yep, most samples are broken because they link to WMS unavailable resources (at least at the time of writing).

Using other resources the samples will work.

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

var ol_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {
            layers: "basic"
        });

var bmTiles = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
        "Geodab Map",
        ["http://tiles.geodab.eu/geodab-tiles/tile/bluemarble/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"],
        {
            numZoomLevels: 10
        });
map.addLayers([ol_wms, bmTiles]);
var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(4, 32, 22, 55);
map.zoomToExtent(extent, true);
```

Comment: would love to see why i got downvoted since at the time of writing those tutorials are still broken.